# Python/Django how to avoid to update a queryset object in memory while update the database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

If I use my view like this:

```
def test(request):
    order = Order.objects.filter(status='new')
    context = {}
    context['order_list'] = order
    return render(request, 'checkout/order.html',context)
```

The context variable `order_list` works fine and it's rendered on the template,
but after get the queryset objet `order` I would like to update the database, so I did it like this:

```
def test(request):
    order = Order.objects.filter(status='new')
    context = {}
    context['order_list'] = order
    Order.objects.filter(id__in=order).update(status='warning') #added this line
    return render(request, 'checkout/order.html',context)
```

The update works fine on the database but also change my context variable `oder_list`, it becomes empty on template.
Why the `order` object is also updated? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you are doing anything wrong per se, but it is just the way Django handles querysets. So when you do

```
order = Order.objects.filter(status='new')
```

The queryset is only "marked" for evaluation, whereas the actual evaluation happens when you are trying to process the records in the template.

That is the reason, when you do

```
Order.objects.filter(id__in=order).update(status='warning')
```

the context variables have the values that reflect the update.

---

It looks like you are trying to update the status to 'warning' if an object has already been viewed - correct ?

If so, one way you can handle this would be - once the page has been rendered, you can send an ajax request to update the status for a list of ids.

Another lesser efficient way would be to evaluate the queryset before the update - something like:

```
context['order_list'] = list(order)
```

Comment: Got it! But is there a way to keep the queryset and send it to template before the evaluation?

Comment: Sorry about the ignorance, but how i do that? hahah, I'm really new with Django.

Comment: how do i do what ?